# Sending data securely from an iOS app to a php script on a server

Tags: ios, ipad, security, networking, https

I'm developing an in house iPad app for a company. Its a simple app that they will use to collect data from people at events. It takes their name, email, phone number, etc. This data will then be sent to a php script on their server which stores it in a database. In order to prevent people from sending any old info to this script, the app will send a password along with the data.

My question is, what is the best approach to sending this data securely across the internet.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Uhm... SSL encryption? If you're paranoid you could encrypt the data with RSA before sending it anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Not much to go on, but basically, unless you have a ***very very*** strong reason not to, just use `https` and count on it protecting your data transmission.

Beyond that, you should consider not storing plain text passwords in the database. You would probably want them hashed to protect the users if the database gets exposed in some way.